# Cordova Sqlite Plugin: Is there any way to inspect a Sqlite database using the Chrome console debug?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, debugging, console

Is there any fast way to inspect a Sqlite database using the Resources Tab in chrome://inspect ?

I'm using the Cordova Sqlite Plugin

[image: chrome debug console]

**If not, what is the fast/best way?** (Currently I can only get through callbacks).

Comment: Are you using a SQLite plugin?

Comment: Yes, Sqlite Plugin :)

Comment: So, AFAIK, there's no way to use Chrome's developer tools to inspect what a plugin is doing. What I've typically done in the past is to make sure that my code will work in a browser as well as the mobile app (the only part that changes much is opening the database). Then you'd be using Chrome's implementation, and as such, Chrome would let you inspect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the plugin, you'll need a native SQLite db browser app. I've used SQLite Editor from Speed Software in the past from the Google Play store, but there may be better options now.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor

Comment: Thank You! This help me.

Comment: Happy to hear that!